# Scheduled Deployment for CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to save our AWS cost. What I am doing right now is to terminate ec2 instances at 8pm then launch them again at 8am. I was able to do this via Skeddly (http://www.skeddly.com/).

The problem is the codes are not update every time I launch an instance because I'm just using an AMI. What I want to find out is, are there any services which I can use to auto deploy codes using CodeDeploy every 8am so that the instances are aligned with the latest codes.

Answer (score 0):

One idea for how you can do this is that you can create a lambda function with a scheduled event: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

In that lambda you can call CodeDeploy with the aws sdk to kick off a deployment. How you determine what is the "latest code" is up to you. If this is from github you can just link to a zip of the head of master for example. Otherwise you need something to kick off an upload of your latest code to S3.